# C Return Value from Function Best Practice

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, return-value, function-definition

What option is recommended in C to return an array from a function?

**Option 1:**

```
void function_a(int *return_array){
    return_array[0] = 1;
    return_array[1] = 0;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
int* function_b(){
    int return_array[2];
    return_array[0] = 1;
    return_array[1] = 0;
    return return_array;
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is invalid. Which leaves the first one (there are unlisted options though..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function

```
int* function_b(){
    int return_array[2];
    return_array[0] = 1;
    return_array[1] = 0;
    return return_array;
}
```

returns a pointer to the first element of a local array with automatic storage duration that will not be alive after exiting the function.

So the returned pointer will be invalid and dereferencing such a pointer invokes undefined behavior.

You could return a pointer to first element of an array from a function if the array is allocated dynamically or has static storage duration that is when it is declared with the storage class specifier `static`.

As for the first function then it will be more safer if you will pass also the number of elements in the array like

```
void function_a(int *return_array, size_t n );
```

and within the function you will be able to check the passed value.

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if I'm wrong, but declaring the variable as static would basically make the ".c" file a singleton and as a beginner I should rather stay away from dynamic memory allocation? So that would leave me with Option 1.

Comment: @PlzBePython Static variable are initialized only once before the program startup. You will often need to allocate dynamically memory when for example you will deal with lists.

Comment: @PlzBePython It is indeed "singletone", but I prefer to think about it as a global, which is only seen in the function (which it basically is). Dynamic allocation is not that "advanced" to stay away from it. But your fist option is viable enough if used properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd most prefer:

```
void function_a(int return_array[const], size_t sz) {
    return_array[0] = 1;
    return_array[1] = 0;
}
```

Because it clearly indicates that the parameter is an Array, and it also clearly indicates the size of the array that is passed in, making out-of-bounds indicies less likely to be a problem.

Comment: something is off in the declaration...

Comment: https://ideone.com/ibUI4S   Working demo.

Comment: But it makes no use of `sz`. I don't remember the exact syntax though, but this one looks off.

Comment: To properly *use* `sz`, I'd have to know what the function actually accomplishes (beyond just making sure that `sz >= 2`.   The OP didn't provide enough information.  My key point is that providing an unsized array is risky and not sufficient.  The size of the array must be know.  The ***use*** of that information is implementation specific.

Comment: It looks like  `void function_a(size_t sz, int return_array[sz])`  would be better. Optionally working in C17/18 but mandatory in C23 if I've understood it correctly.

Comment: But what the `int return_array[const]` is accomplishing? What this `const` is telling it?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That `const` makes the pointer that results from the parameter adjustment be `const`-qualified, as if the parameter declaration were `int * const return_array`.

Comment: The `const` prevents `return_array` from being assigned to another array or variable. Most importantly, it cannot be assigned to a local/automatic array, so it helps clearly indicate that the array will be filled in, but will not be used for any other purpose (like a temporary variable) within the function.

Comment: Oh, OK. I though it was added here with some other intention. Something similar to `void function_a(int return_array[static 2])`

Comment: @Eric Could you specify the section where the C standard talks about this? Thank you.

Comment: @Haris: C 2018 6.7.6.2 specifies array declarators and paragraph 3 refers to 6.7.6.3 for the meaning of qualifiers in the brackets. 6.7.6.3 specifies function declarators, and paragraph 7 says that qualifiers in the brackets of an array parameter apply to the pointer that the array parameter is adjusted to.